# How to add an actual user id into react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

Issue: I have a current placeholder as an id and i assigned it to number 5.

Request: I need to implement a way to add a user id instead, but I'm not sure how to do that.

here is my code

```
const submitFeedbackForm = async () => {
    feedbackFormDispatch({ type: FEEDBACK_FORM_SUBMIT });
    try {
      await axios.post("/api/feedback", {
        rating,
        age,
        userId: 5,// here where i need to do it.
        covidImpact,
        generalFeedback,
        mostValuableFeature,
        whatWouldChange,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      const message = err.response?.data?.message || err.message;
      feedbackFormDispatch({
        type: FEEDBACK_FORM_SUBMIT_ERROR,
        error: `Could not submit feedback, reason: ${message}`,
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Where ever you're making the call to your `submitFeedbackForm` method, you'll need to pass it the user id as an argument and then you can use it in your function as so:

```
const submitFeedbackForm = async (userId) => {
...
userId: userId,// here where i need to do it.
=
...
```

Tip: you can name your parameter the same as the property name, effectively reducing `userId: userId,` to simply `userId,`.

More preferably, if user is an object, then you'll want to get into the habit of passing the object reference instead. The benefit of doing this is by being able to access all the properties of user instead of having to pass in several arguments which is generally bad practice.

That would look something like this:

```
const submitFeedbackForm = async (user) => {
...
userId: user.id, // <- assuming your user object contains the property id
=
...
```

Comment: so the system will generate a different user id by simply adding the async(user) and then pass it into the UserId: user.id? interesting. I thought it would more complicated

Answer (score 1):

### Use timestemp

`Date.now()` will give you a unique number like now `1594183969106`.

```
userId: Date.now(),
```

or as a string with some repeat word

```
userId: `user-id-${Date.now()}`,
```

- This is not the perfect solution for a multi-user app